# AWT-EventQueue-0 error

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I have written the following code. Basically I want to activate autocomplete (in a RSyntaxTextArea environment) if the entered character is not space. Everything is working smoothly, but the fact that sometimes I will get the AWT-EventQueue-0 error. The program will still run and function but the error message shows up.

I have other elements in my code, but I am quite sure it is from this bit of added code. Any particular reason for this? I have noticed this error happening when I move the mouse to a second screen.

```
public static CompletionProvider provider = createModelCompletionProvider();

public static AutoCompletion ac = new AutoCompletion(provider);

public static KeyListener ListenerTOntology = new KeyListener() {

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
dumpInfo("Typed", e);}

private void dumpInfo(String s, KeyEvent e) {
    char temp = e.getKeyChar();
    if(temp!=' ' )
   ac.doCompletion();}
};
```

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.FoldIndicator.findOpenFoldClosestTo(FoldIndicator.java:162)
at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.FoldIndicator.access$300(FoldIndicator.java:60)
at org.fife.ui.rtextarea.FoldIndicator$Listener.mouseMoved(FoldIndicator.java:671)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseMoved(AWTEventMulticaster.java:329)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6550)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3339)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6274)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4505)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: *"I have other elements in my code, but I am quite sure it is from this bit of added code."*  The stack trace should tell you.  Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & we might also know.

Comment: So what code is in `FoldIndicator.findOpenFoldClosestTo`? Around line 162 of `FoldIndicator.java`?

Comment: That is the RSyntaxTextArea.jar file. I can't find the source file to see what is inside it. I am looking though.

Comment: Basically this is the link: http://tinyurl.com/bquuq75

Comment: Probably not related to your question, assuming RSyntaxTextArea is based on a Swing component you should be using a DocumentListener, not a KeyListener to listen for user input. For example what happens when the user hit the backspace or delete keys?

Comment: Actually the backspace and delete keys work perfectly. I should stay all the keys work nicely. Also, can I use a documentlistener when I have multiple textareas? I couldn't find a documentlistener option for RSyntaxTextArea.

Comment: Based on the code you provided I don't see how it works. You only do something when a character is typed. Those keys don't generate displayable characters so you autocompletion code should not be invoked. A DocumentListener is added to the Document of the Swing text component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I discovered what caused this. You need to use a CaretListener instead of KeyListener. Since RSyntaxTextArea does not contain a DocumentListner.